# Facebook new "inline" like buttons

Tags: facebook-like, inline

In the past few days I noticed that, whenever I share a webpage from some website which has a facebook page  and I haven't liked this page yet, I get a like button, on my newsfeed saying "want to see more about xyz ?" and a "like page" button. This functionality, however is not there for every website/page I've tested with and I'd like to know if there is any change we need to do either on the Facebook page or on the website to make this "magic" happen :-)

thanks, 
P

Comment: I'm guessing since it is not there for some websites/pages but is present for others it may be a paid advertising feature. It's just a guess as I've gone through the docs and can't see anything that could account for it. I'd say get in touch with the Facebook sales team.

Comment: Actually it's being rolled out as stated here http://wildhairmedia.com/2013/03/04/new-facebook-features-coming-to-your-news-feed/ ... the question is that it appears for some pages and not to others (it doesn't seem to be by fan count, or og meta tags)...

Comment: If that's the case then I'd wait and see.  If it's being rolled out at the moment it will probably either happen automatically or the docs will catch up to tell you what else needs to be done to implement it.  Sorry I can't give a definitive answer on this one.